# Can not calculate on decimal number

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcxRF.png]

Please click on the link to see my image

Here is my code. I don't understand why its always false only decimal number. What should I do?

```
Sub calcu()

Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim d As Integer

Dim g1 As Double
Dim g2 As Double
Dim hdp As Double
Dim ts1 As Double
Dim ts2 As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

a = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For b = 1 To a
  If IsNumeric(Cells(b, "C").Value) Then
    hdp = Cells(b, "G")

    ts1 = Cells(b, "L")
    ts2 = Cells(b, "M")
    t1 = Cells(b, "F")
    t2 = Cells(b, "H")
    g1 = ts1 - hdp
    g2 = ts2 - hdp

    v1 = 1.72
    v2 = 2.1
    v3 = 1.9
    v4 = 1.8
    v5 = 2

    If InStr(t1, "K") And g1 < ts2 Then
      Cells(b, "J") = "0"
    ElseIf InStr(t1, "K") And g1 = ts2 Then
      Cells(b, "E") = 1
      Cells(b, "J") = 1
    ElseIf InStr(t2, "K") And g2 < ts1 Then
      Cells(b, "E") = "0"
    ElseIf InStr(t2, "K") And g2 = ts1 Then
      Cells(b, "E") = 1
      Cells(b, "J") = 1
    Else
      Cells(b, "E") = "error"
      Cells(b, "J") = "error"
    End If
  End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring to why you're getting `error`, it's nothing to do with the decimal numbers.

Your test for row 2 is doing `5` (Column L) - `1.5` (Column G), which equals 3.5. You then test if that is less than 1, or equal to 1 (Column M). It's not, so you're getting `error`.

The test fails all the way down where you have a letter G in Column H, as the number you end up with is larger than the number in Column M, which it is testing against.

As I have no idea what you're trying to do or what the result should be, I can't help you any further, but the reason it's failing isn't due to decimals, it's actually doing the exact tests you told it to, and coming up with the correct results.